# How can I pass the same object to another method of another object?

Tags: c++, object

Say I have an object of type Game instantiated somewhere, and I have another class called Writer where I want to save it....

So in `Writer` class I have....

```
void gameWriter(Game g) {
  some wonderful logic here....

}
```

And inside `Game`, I want to call `gameWriter`... so I have a method that goes like this (inside `Game`)

```
void Game::saveGameDetails() {

    Writer w;
    w.gameWriter(this);  //this is where it fails...

}
```

How can I call `gameWriter` within `Game` using that same object I am currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be syntactically correct, you need to use:

```
w.gameWriter(*this);
```

I would further suggest the use of `Game const&` or `Game&` as the argument type in `gameWriter`.

```
void gameWriter(Game const& g) { ... }
```

Then you will save on the cost of creating a copy of the `Game`.

Comment: I get this error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Writer::gameWriter(Game&)", referenced from:
      Game::saveGameDetails() in Game-3b77f1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: It's hard to figure out how to fix linker errors without seeing all the files and all the lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you pass a pointer `this` while according to the signature of  `gameWriter`, it expects the object itself. Try this

```
void Game::saveGameDetails()
{
    Writer w;
    w.gameWriter(*this);  
}
```

Comment: I have a tough time with pointers in C++, so inside gameWriter declaration I should use void gameWriter(Game *g);?

Comment: @MarcoBerrocal this is also an option but then inside `gameWriter` you will have to dereference it in order to access the methods/fields of `Game`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but try declaring Writer() as a static class. Then, you don't need to instantiate it in your instance of Game, just call Writer.Save(this);

I suggest this because I am guessing the error is occurring when you pass an instance of game to the instance of gameWriter(), but since w is inside of Game, things might get weird.